# Where activity results are sent to, if new activity is started for result and then main activity closed?

Tags: android, android-activity, onactivityresult

I am starting new activity for result (let's name it `Activity3`), but then immediately finish the main activity (`Activity2`):

```
mActivity.startActivityForResult(mIntent, PICK_USER_PHONE);
finish();
```

in result, `onActivityResult` is not called. Does it mean that result from `Activity3` is lost? Or can I get that in some other activity (for example in `Activity1`, which started `Activity2`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you finish, yes, it is lost.

If you want `Activity1` to receive it, you have to start `Activity2` for result, then start `Activity3` for result, then receive the result on `Activity2` and then you can `finish()` `Activity2` and pass the result back to `Activity1`